# Why I get different results when running code in R Markdown with knitr than in R script

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have an R code that I've written which is in a normal `.r` file, now I want to make a markdown html report so I'm basically running the same code, but in chunks with text in between.
I have the weirdest problem where some code works as it worked in the regular r file, but some code produces different results entirely. For example:

```
mydata_complete_obs %>% select(-(prom_id:end_a)) %>% select(qualified, everything()) %>%
                                          cor(use = "complete.obs", method = "spearman") %>% 
                                          corrplot(type = "lower", method = "circle", diag = F, insig = "pch", addCoef.col = "grey",
                                                   p.mat = res1$p, title = "Spearman Correlations")
```

The above code which produces a `corrplot` does work and produces the same graph as I get in the `.r` file, but a simple `summary()` function gives me different things - the correct output being produced in the `.r` file and in the markdown report I get all zeroes (min, 1st quartile, median, mean, etc. - all 0!). This is the chunk for the `summary()`:

````
```{r hists, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, error = 
   FALSE, results="markup"}
   summary(mydata_complete_obs)
```
````

What can be wrong? I'm loading all the libraries and read in the data from an `.rds` file in the first chunk, and then later use `mydata_complete_obs` to produce graphs and summaries. If I understand correctly I don't need to load the data for each chunk separately, because I thought that was the problem.

Comment: Why did you put a code working well but not mention what's wrong about your `summary()` function more detailedly ?

Comment: Because it is just a plain `summary()`, but for any case - I edited the post.

Comment: Difficult to diagnose without more background. First guesses: Different working directories, different code executed before... Add "debug code" (prints) to both variants to find the differences...

Comment: @RYoda: How do I do that? what is the command? As for the directories - they are both the same. It cant be a different code executed before because the corrplot takes exactly the same dataset and it works. The `summary()` output just shows zeroes!

Comment: @Corel Add `str(mydata_complete_obs)`, `getwd()` and others in a chunk that shows the output, then you can see the values in the generated report. RStudio renders RMDs in a separate R session where you do NOT have access to workspace variables of RStudio...

Comment: @RYoda: I have checked that and it seems that when my data loads in the R-Markdown report, it loads with different numbers (also everything appears in scientific notation in a strange way). By the way, I read the data from an .RDS file which has my dataframe saved. In the R script it loads as it should. I'm puzzled.

Comment: In addition - when I load my `.RDS` file, the numeric columns all appear in an `integer64` format, its only these columns that end up being different between the two attempts, and yes, the difference is there even before I convert them to `dbl` with `as.numeric`

Comment: This is so weird - when I quit R-Studio and then open it again and read my `.rds` file, **even in the r script** it gives me the wrong numbers now. It is if the `.rds` files changes after R-Studio reloads...what can I do?? (in that case I need to read the data again from the database and save it again to a `.rds` file which is really time consuming, and it never works in the R-Markdown anyway..

Comment: @Corel Without a minimal reproducible example in your question we have no chance to answer your question without speculation. Please reduce your code to a minimal size that provokes the problem and add this code to your question (+ incl. minimal input + expected output data).THX#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem. I had to change the query in the database so that the format of the columns will be `INT` instead of `BIGINT` (that's in Impala), then when I read it in R, everything worked and the strange behaviour disappeared.